# Unable to create new xamarin shared project, couldn't build existing xamarin project in visual studio Professional 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

While creating a new project, it shows two errors:

**1. Package Installation Error**

Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\XAMARIN\XAMARIN\4.0.3.214\Packages':

**2. Xamarin.Forms.2.0.0.6482**

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=v1.0', but the package doesn't contain any assembly reference or content that are compatible

I have tried different options to change build configuration using:
Right Click Solution -> Configuration -> Build (Check/Uncheck)
but nothing works for me :(

When I try to build the existing solutions, it shows:

> App1.dll could not be found.

I have also setup Android SDK, NDK and iOS SDK as well but still couldn't build the project.

Comment: Can you link to your version info there? > Visual Studio
Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info [button]

Comment: Sure, see the version info at http://pastie.org/10835495

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your version information there it looks like you're running NuGet Package Manager 2.7.4.  The newer NuGet release corresponds to later framework versions including the Xamarin Unified API.  Please try updating to 2.8.6 and trying again:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have downloaded NuGet PM 2.8.6, right now I am also installing Visual Studio 2015. Will let you know as soon as VS 2015 is installed.

Comment: VS2015 actually has a later version of NuGet :) This should be installed along with the rest of VS2015 but in case it isn't: https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. It means Visual Studio 2013 will automatically build existing solutions after VS 2015 installation.